# Where to put test class for "normal" Ruby classes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

I have created a module in the `lib` directory (it seems to be the place where you put it). It has one method that is useful for many of my model classes.

I want to unit test it. However when I try to put a test in the `model` folder in `test` it fails:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass
```

So it is probably wrong. Where should the test be, and what should it inherit etc to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your tests almost always just follow the same folder structure.  So if you have:

```
app
├── controllers
├── models
```

Your tests directory would be:

```
spec
├── controllers
│   └── some_controller_spec.rb
├── models
│   ├── some_model_spec.rb
├── rails_helper.rb
└── spec_helper.rb
```

In your instance, if you have a lib folder, you'd simply add a lib folder to your spec/test directory.